# mpmath.exp together with sympy.exp in python

Tags: python

I am writing a code the needs at the same time to deal with very big and very small factors and to perform symbolic integrals.
As far as I know, this means I need both mpmath and sympy modules, is it right?
More "dramatically" I need to use the exponential function from both the modules. 
I imported the following functions:

```
from sympy import Symbol, integrate, exp
from scipy.constants import *
from mpmath import mpf, sqrt, exp, pi, besselj, erf
```

and I tried to use mpmath.exp() and sympy.exp() where needed but I got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'mpmath' is not defined
```

even if the mpmath module has been imported. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import sympy
from scipy.constants import *
import mpmath
```

Using `mpmath.exp()` and `sympy.exp()` should then work.

The `import` forms you are using make e.g. `mpmath.exp()` and `sympy.exp()` just `exp()` (which likely means there is a naming conflict between these two functions anyway).